# C typedef for undeclared structure is not throwing any compilation error

Tags: c, struct, structure, typedef

I am just wondering how `typedef` is not throwing any compilation error when its used with undeclared structure. Below code is compiling without any warning and error. My doubt is how come a `typedef` with undeclared structure is not throwing any error. Is it same in all platforms

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct undeclared_struct_st UND_STRUCT_S;

int main()
{
    printf("\nhello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am executing this program in Suse 11 with gcc 4.3.4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
typdef struct undeclared_struct_st UND_STRUCT_S;
```

is valid. It declares `struct undeclared_struct_st` as an incompele type and then declares `UND_STRUCT_S` as a typedef to `struct undeclared_struct_st`. You cannot create objects of incomplete type but you can create pointers to objects of incomplete type. `struct undeclared_struct_st` can then be declared in another translation unit.

Answer (score 5):

This is called a forward declaration, and it is perfectly legal C.

Comment: Stating the name of something is not an explanation of what it is, how it works, or what its characteristics are.